# Is API Gateway *required* to make an API on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to determine if it's possible to build an API on AWS *without* using API Gateway. Is API Gateway just meant to make it more convenient, or is it impossible without it?

Comment: It's entirely possible to build an API on AWS without API Gateway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon API Gateway is a managed service meant to make things easier. From the product page:

> Amazon API Gateway is a fully managed service that makes it easy for
>   developers to create, publish, maintain, monitor, and secure APIs at
>   any scale. With a few clicks in the AWS Management Console, you can
>   create an API that acts as a “front door” for applications to access
>   data, business logic, or functionality from your back-end services,
>   such as workloads running on Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon
>   EC2), code running on AWS Lambda, or any web application.

However, nothing prevents you from spinning up your own api using any combination of their other resources.

Answer (score 0):

Can you publish a WEBSITE on AWS without the API Gateway? One that runs custom code?

If the answer is yes - what stops you from publishing a website that takes requests and answers in JSON. Which is exactly what a REST API is. HTML or JSON is really an implementation detail of your website program.

Answer (score 0):

AWS API Gateway is particularly useful if your backend is hosted in AWS Lambda. You can trigger Lambda functions from API Gateway. You can absolutely roll your own API / web service without it.